# Re-Initializing static members in PHP

Tags: php, static

I have a question in my todays Exam in which I have to determine the output.

```
<?php
function statfun($x)
{
    static $count=0;

    $count += $x;

    if ($count < 20) {
        echo "$count <br>";
        statfun(++$x);
    } else {
        echo "last num is $count";
    }
}

statfun(2);
?>
```

The output is

```
2
5
9
14
last num is 20
```

I dont know why this is the output. I know it is due to the static member but each time it comes into the function the member `$count` is re-initialized.I had saw the documentation at [Static Keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

But there is nothing written regarding the re-initialization of static variable? Can we re-initialize the static variable in PHP? With the same or any other value?

Comment: *i dont know why this is the output.i know it is due to the static member* ... I'm confused, what do you want to know then? The `static` keyword in classes is something different. Have a look at [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: I do not follow. Can you elaborate what do you mean by " _re-initialize the static variable in php_ "?

Comment: I mean to say that this output is due to the static member.If we remove the static word from it the output will be entirely differennt

Comment: @Tadeck we are calling the function again and again statfunc().Whenever we will call the function the static members are re-initialized or not?

Comment: No, if they were initialized once, they are not initialized again - this is how static variables in functions work. They store the value they were assigned, even if the assignment took place in different call of the same function.

Comment: @sharpzain: If it helps, you can pretend that PHP **DELETES** the `static $x = 0` code after it's executed the first time, meaning it won't be there and won't executed again the next time the function is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> each time it comes into the function the member $count is re-initialized

This is incorrect. Static variables are initialized only *once* which is how statically declared variables differ from "ordinary" variables. So basically, you're assigning an initial value to `$count`. In multiple calls to `statfun()`, this static variable's value is preserved and can be reused.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), section "Using static variables":

> A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

Also look at the example-code in the manual. The difference stated there should answer your question.

Comment: but why it doesnt give an errot like re-declaring a variable like in java or c++.It cant ignore the line static $count=0;

Comment: ...because it's not *being* redeclared.

Comment: @Sharpzain120 You are wrong. In C++ the `static` keyword in a function has exactly the same effect as it does in PHP: it prevents the re-initialization of the variable.

Comment: @Linus @ Aillyn what will the "PHP compiler" when it interprets the line $count=0 at each function call?

Comment: @Sharpzain120 In Java, there are no functions to speak of and you can't declare variables to be `static` in a method. `static` variables in Java are class variables. They behave like `static` variables in a class context in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: @Sharpzain120 It sees the `static` keyword and does nothing if has already been initialized.

Answer (score 3):

when you pass 2 count is set to 2
with `$count+=$x;`
then you have called `statfun(++$x)` which is `$x+1` and that is `2+1=3`
so now $count will be `$count+3` and that is 5, and then you call statfun with the value of 3 then $count will **$count+(3+1) = 9** and so on and so on

static variable will hold its state. So if you call it like this

So basically static variable will hold its value and will not be re-initialized.

Comment: i know the flow,basically what i want to ask is that whenever we enter in the function static $count=0.This statement initilize the count to 0.Why you are using the previous value of $count?

Comment: @Sharpzain120: Because the `static` keyword explicitly states to keep the previous value.

Comment: @FelixKling what will the "PHP compiler" when it interprets the line $count=0 at each function call?

Comment: compiler will ignore static $count=0; if its already declared in that method, and compiler will not compile same method twice, by the way.